# How to quote and link in a comment

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

Is there any easy way to quote in a comment?
You can quote in a question or an answer easily.
Just put ">" in front of the quoted statements.
However, this does not work in a comment.

Similarly you can write a link in a question or an answer by writing, for example, [here][1]
and [1]:the linked address.
However, this does not work in a comment.

Sorry if the solutions are well known.

Comment: [How to format links in comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/how-to-format-links-in-comments),
[Creating a Hyperlink in a Comment Box](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/creating-a-hyperlink-in-a-comment-box),
[How do you cite a reference in a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-do-you-cite-a-reference-in-a-comment). See also the part of [editing help about comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can quote by simply using quotation marks. You can write a link in a post or comment like [this](url here), for example [google link](http://www.google.com).

Comment: Note that the URL needs the `http://` part.  E.g. [Google](http://www.google.com) vs. [Google](www.google.com).

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the block quote formatting is available in comments, but you could also just use quotation marks, "[text]" or «[text]».  You could get gray background if preferred by using `[text]`, which would result in `[text]`.

(The rest was answered as I was writing.)

Comment: `testing gray background`

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot.

Comment: `But MathJax doesn't seem to work on gray background: $\frac{\sin x}{n} = 6$`